# Owl Carousel Slider not working in Ruby on Rails 5.1.4

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to implement owl carousel in my rails app.but the owl carousel won't display. In my `gem file` i have added the following gems.

```html
gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 4.3', '>= 4.3.1'
gem 'popper_js', '~> 1.12.9'
gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.0.0.beta2.1'
gem 'owlcarousel-rails', '~> 1.1', '>= 1.1.3.3'
```

And in `application.js` the code looks like

```js
//= require jquery3
//= require popper
//= require bootstrap
//= require owl.carousel
//= require active
//= require rails-ujs
//= require turbolinks
```

And my `active.js` contains this code

```js
(function ($) {
    'use strict';

    
// :: 1.0 Owl Carousel Active Code
    if ($.fn.owlCarousel) {
        $(".welcome_slides").owlCarousel({
            items: 1,
            loop: true,
            autoplay: true,
            smartSpeed: 1500,
            nav: true,
            navText: ["<i class='pe-7s-angle-left'</i>", "<i class='pe-7s-angle-right'</i>"]
        });
        $(".app_screenshots_slides").owlCarousel({
            items: 1,
            loop: true,
            autoplay: true,
            smartSpeed: 800,
            margin: 30,
            center: true,
            dots: true,
            responsive: {
                0: {
                    items: 1
                },
                480: {
                    items: 3
                },
                992: {
                    items: 5
                }
            }
        });
    }

})(jQuery);
```

Code of `application.css` is

```css
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
```

And in `Style.css.scss` i have to import these two css.

```
@import "bootstrap";
@import "owl.carousel";
```

And in my `index.html.erb` file code is

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <!-- App Screenshots Slides  -->
                    <div class="app_screenshots_slides owl-carousel">
                        <div class="single-shot">
                            
                            <%=image_tag("scr-img/1.png", alt: "")%>
                        </div>
                        <div class="single-shot">
                            <%=image_tag("scr-img/2.png", alt: "")%>
                        </div>
                        <div class="single-shot">
                            <%=image_tag("scr-img/3.png", alt: "")%>
                        </div>
                        <div class="single-shot">
                            <%=image_tag("scr-img/4.png", alt: "")%>
                        </div>
                        <div class="single-shot">
                            <%=image_tag("scr-img/1.png", alt: "")%>
                        </div>
      <div class="single-shot">
                            <%=image_tag("scr-img/3.png", alt: "")%>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

My rails version is 5.1.4 and ruby version is 2.4.3p205.

Comment: did you tried adding owl.theme as well?

Comment: Do you have a url we can see this in action? Do you have any js errors or missing files?